# Dynamic checkbox with Ajax in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Form with some checkboxes loaded from the Database, and an option to add other items manually to the items table. This is done by Ajax in the code below...

**item_controller.rb**

```
   def manual_item_add
      @manual_item = Item.find(params[:id_item].to_i)     
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
   end
```

**manual_item_add.js.erb**

```
$("#items_table").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'manual_item_add', :manual_item => @manual_item) %>")
```

**_manual_item_add.html.erb**

```
...
<td><%= check_box_tag("manual_items[]", item.id, true) %></td>
...
```

**edit_items.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_tag( {controller:"item", action:"edit_items"}) do %>
      <p align="center">
         <%= select_date(@account.start_date, prefix: 'start_date') %>        
      to 
         <%= select_date(@account.end_date, prefix: 'end_date') %>          
      </p>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'id_account', @account.id %>
      <table id="items_table" class="subtable" align="center" width="55%"> 

            .... 
          <tr>
             <th colspan="6">Items added manually</th>
          </tr>               
          <tr>
             <th># ID</th>
             <th>Type</th>
             <th>Description</th>
             <th>Ammount</th>
             <th>Date</th>
             <th>Include in the account</th>
          </tr>
   </table>

   <p align="center"><%= submit_tag("Save", class: "btn") %></p>
<% end %>


<%= form_tag( {controller:"item", action:"manual_item_add"}, method:"get", remote: true) do %>
   <h4 align="center">Add item manually</h4>
   <p align="center">Item ID:
     <%= text_field_tag "item_id", nil , size:5, maxlength:5 %>
     <%= submit_tag("Add Item", class: "light_btn") %>
   </p>
<% end %>
```

So... the problem here is that though I see the new checkboxes i am adding to the table (they are being created normally), the ***"manual_items[]"*** array is not being passed to the controller when I submit the resulting form (by the way, the "items_table" is inside the form definition).

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Sorry for the newbie question, I'm starting to work with Ruby + Rails.

Comment: post your form please in which you are appending this

Comment: @Deep I've just included the forms... you can see the second form which sends the Ajax request - the table "items_table" in the first form is the one who receives the new checkbox items - it is inside the form, so I don't know what is missing. By the way, the items ARE being created inside the table, but the parameter "manual_items" doesn't even show up in the request after submitting.

Comment: Try this once: `<td><%= check_box_tag("item[manual_items][]", item.id, true) %></td>`

Comment: @Deep, I tried, but it didn't work... no new parameter in the form submission. The new checkboxes somehow are not being recognized as part of the form. I remain without knowing how to proceed...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have a definitive answer for this problem. The only working solution I've tried was to use JQuery to force parameters to be part of the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#edit_items_form").submit(function(event) {
      $(this).append($("input[name='manual_items[]']:checked"));                
      $(this).submit();
  });  
});
```

I am definitely not comfortable to this solution, I'd like to know why these Ajax checkboxes are not automatically recognized as being part the form.